# How to create a pasting macro

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, copy-paste, keybindings

I'm a big fan of the ANSI keyboard layout, but since I'm located in Denmark, the layout is missing the three letters 'Æ', 'Ø' and 'Å'.

I want to create three keyboard shortcuts that triggers a paste of one of these three letters into whatever text writing in.

From my research, it has to be a paste event that triggers the writing of one of the letters. Since the OS has registered an ANSI layout, it can't type 'Æ', 'Ø' and 'Å'.

I've made it 'sorta' work with Keyboard Maestro, but my trial has ended, and I've made AppleScripts in Automator, that rarely triggers. (Some issue Accessibility).

I've looked around a lot, and can't seem to find a solid and free/cheap solution. Can somebody help me out?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

The AppleScript I've tried to use with Automator.

```
on run {input, parameters)
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "Æ"
    end tell
end run
```

This requires me to enable it under *System Preferences > Keyboard > Services* and afterwards enable an application where it want to use it 
 at *System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Accessibility*

After that's done, the script is really slow, and will often not register a tricker.

**My keyboard:**
[image: My ANSI WhiteFox keyboard]

Comment: What I would do: Get [**Ukelele**](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ukelele) and use it to create a new keyboard layout using the ANSI keyboard as a starting point. (I'd make this into an answer, but my experience with ukelele is too outdated for me to offer detailed advice. Note that there are [many posts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=ukelele) about Ukelele on the site, though.)

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :) In addition to the advice offered by @HaraldHanche-Olsen - if you're still interested in other answers you may want to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/367128/edit) your question to also provide the AppleScript code you came up with and to clarify what you meant by *"...that rarely triggers. (Some issue Accessibility)."*?

Comment: Can you post a picture of your keyboard? I've just checked UK & US English & all 3 of those characters can be generated holding the Opt key, or Opt/Shift for caps, on keys o a & '

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHDZp.jpg

Comment: @Monomeeth Thanks! I've added those information now... :)

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Cool! I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @Tetsujin Holy Sh't! I didn't know that there was a second layer of characters. Thank you, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to find a solution from @Tetsujin's comment. Using the keyboard configurator for the WhiteFox keyboard, I created a layer of A, O and '. I then use a fn key together with alt/opt (+ shift for CAPS) to write Æ, Ø and Å.

[image: Keyboard layout of solution]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text Replacement, built into the system.
The issue with needing to generate a single letter in the middle of a word is that the replacer generally wants you to hit a space or a period then a space before it will do the replacement. You also need the trigger to be something you wouldn't ordinarily type.

See System Prefs > Keyboard > Text

For instance, if you set your input to 'ae' & your output to 'Æ' then you would trigger every time you typed ae followed by a space… probably not very useful.
So, you generate with a mnemonic instead. I used §ae as it's easy to do that on my ISO keyboard; on ANSI you might pick `ae or ~ae or similar.

That, however, will still need you to generate a space afterwards, then backspace it - irritating.
So, this is the trick - the only downside is it will now take 5 key-presses to generate one character.
Set your input to §ae..
2 full-stops [periods] at the end.

That will let you trigger the replacement *without* having to enter a space, so you can use it in the middle of a word.

[image]

BTW, you just copy/paste into the right-hand side, or double-click it from the Emoji & Symbols panel, if you can't make your keyboard naturally generate a character

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was really hoping for a keyboard shortcut, however it's not a must. I've tried your solution and it seems to work fine in email. But it doesn't seem to work in the Youtube search bar, Word or Facebook messenger .